# Illustrator different color stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, stroke

Is it possible to paint only inside a stroke on illustrator? what i actually want to do is paint the same stroke with different colors in diferent segments of it but i can't do it...

Also... I've seen some tutorials that include editing a gradient but that would be very complicated and so would be to make a new stroke over this one, I just hope theres an easyer way XD

### *Edit per comment:*

thats cool but not really what im looking for, what i want is lets say my stroke has the shape of a burger i want part of i to be bread color and part of it to be meat color... not one stroke over the other... i want something like this, imagine the jelly worm is my stroke:

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/illustrator-adding-multiple-stroke-to-type-layer-on-outside-in-cs6?rq=1

Answer (score 15):

Simply apply the gradient to the stroke and adjust the options ....

[image: stroke grad]

Only possible in Illustrator CS6 or newer.

Make your own worms...... :)

[image: worms]

Or the burger shape....

[image: buger]

**A gradient is the *only* way to have more than one color assigned to a single stroke.** You can use the Appearance Panel to stack strokes of varying colors, but if you want one stroke to change mid-stream, so to speak, you must use a gradient.

Comment: i dont really want to make worms :D my stroke is really complex thats why I would like some other way than the gradient XD

Comment: I was just playing around. The principle of applying a gradient to the stroke will work for any number of things. :) Is there a reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: ok... just in case... theres no way to group an image inside the stroke?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand that. If you want a stroke around several objects, group the objects, then add a stroke in the Appearance Panel, move it below the "Content" and apply color and size to the stroke. See the "related" question I linked too in the comments above: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/illustrator-adding-multiple-stroke-to-type-layer-on-outside-in-cs6/16944#16944

Comment: @Scott you forgot a cheeseburger... :)

Answer (score 5):

From what you are looking to do you would:

- Create the text
- In the `Appearance Panel` the default should be black but click white.
- Create a gradient by going to `Window > Gradient` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
- After creating the gradient drag it in the `Swatches Panel`.
- Go back to the `Appearance Panel` and create a new fill layer under the fill color of your text, which should be white.
- Select the gradient you created from the Drop down when you click the below fill
- With the lower fill selected go to `Effect > Path > Offset Path` and mess with the settings.

It should take your gradient and make what appears as an outer stroke.

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: first of all thanks for the help, it is a good idea. bu my stroke is way more complicated than that, i will try to do what you sugested but if anyone knows any other way i'll be happy to learn

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question but it seems the poster didn't get what he is asking for. Hopefully this will help anyone who stumbles on this.

It seems like what the poster is actually looking for is a clipping mask.
[image: A clipping mask where the words "Extra extra" are used as a "mold".]

His comment on Scott's answer:

> ok... just in case... theres no way to group an image inside the stroke?

A clipping path is basically cutting through a certain image or shape or group of shapes by using another shape as a "mold" to cut through it. (Think cookie-cutter)

It's a very useful feature and is a bit similar to masks in Photoshop. Here's how to do a clipping path.

1) Select the shape you want to cut through (In this example, the red losange pattern)

2) Select the shape you want to use as the "mold" (in this example, the words "Extra Extra"). (Note: if you're using type as a "mold", it doesn't need to be outlined and can be live-edited. If you're using multiple shapes as the mold, they must be grouped together **but not grouped with the shape you want to cut through.** The same applies to the contrary. When using multiple shapes as the background shape, they must be grouped together, but you cannot group them with the mold.

3) Make sure the "mold" is on top of the shape you want to cut through. (Right click -> arrange -> bring to front"

4) Select both shapes.

5) Make clipping path using right click -> "Make clipping mask" or the "Object -> Clipping Mask -> Make" menu. (This won't be available if both objects are grouped together.

6) You can then "release" the path or move it using the direct selection.