# How to apply a gradient effect for a particular circular path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

[image]

I want to apply a gradient effect and have it look like in this image.

Comment: no image attached.

Comment: you might want to Google around for the 'Gradient Mesh' tool.

Comment: I believe Scott's answer here contains the answer to your question, and gummy worms! [Illustrator different color stroke](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22333/illustrator-different-color-stroke)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this if you have **Illustrator CS6 or newer** is to just apply a gradient to a thick stroke:

[image]

You can then use `Object > Expand Appearance` to convert the stroke to a gradient mesh shape for further manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I found in Adobe Illustrator these both are in envelope distort command under Object Menu::

1. Envelope with Warp
2. Envelope with Mesh

Take a rectangle or any shape put gradient inside it and run these two commands to modify your shapes and the gradient will run in the same direction.