# How to curve a line into an arc along a circle in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

I would like to create a shape similar to this, and I was thinking of using a line and then bending it along a circle, but I'm not sure how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Draw a circle.
- Press <kbd>P</kbd> and click on the actual circle in 2 places (see below). The cursor changes when you're directly above the line.
- Press <kbd>A</kbd> and drag to select one of the points you added then hit <kbd>DEL</kbd> to remove that.
- With this shape selected, in the Stroke panel increase the weight value until it looks thick enough and click the 'Round Cap' option.
- Hit <kbd>R</kbd> and drag around to rotate the object and adjust the gap position.
- And this is how you add a gradient: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/30344/62949

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a circle, and then add some extra anchor points to it (**Object > Path > Add Anchor points** and do it a few times)

(You can also just add the extra points via the *Pen Tool* <kbd>P</kbd>)

Then use the *Direct Selection Tool* (<kbd>A</kbd>) to select and a delete a few anchor points from one corner:

[image]

Now apply a thicker stroke to it and go to **Window > Stroke** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>);

set the *Cap* to *rounded*

Now just apply a gradient to it.

[image]