# How to extend the circular line in this design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have downloaded some Illustrator template. I want to make the circular black line for Norwegian about 90%. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: Relevant: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110511/63979

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a lot easier to draw a new circle from scratch than to manipulate an existing one. Illustrator doesn't recognize the shape as part of a circle so it can't guess what you are trying to do. Actually I would redraw all the circles to make sure that they all have the exact same appearance.

Here is one out of many ways to do this.

[image]

Draw a new ellipse using the *Ellipse Tool*. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to keep it circular. Make the fill color transparent and the stroke color black. Use the *Stroke* panel to set the desired *Weight* (experiment to find a suitable weight) and make sure to set *Align Stroke* to *Center*.

Make sure the circle is selected and double-click the *Rotate Tool*. This opens a dialog where you can enter how many degrees you want to rotate the circle. I enter 36 degrees to rotate the circle 10% (360 / 10 = 36) and press *OK*.

Now, select the *Pen Tool*, make sure that *Smart Guides* are on and you can add a new anchor point in the top of the circle.

It can be a little bit tricky to hit the right spot. You might need to zoom in.

All you need to do now is to deselect the circle and then use the *Direct Selection Tool* to select the unwanted circle segment and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much....Why my questions must be close often or downvoted? :-(

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for something non-destructive and easily edited, you *could* merely use a **Dashed Stroke**.

Set the `Dash` length long enough that it creates a solid stroke.... then adjust the **`Gap`** to add, well, the gap.

[image]

If you want the gap in a *specific location* merely *rotate* the circle afterwards to position the gap where you want it.

---

If you want possibly a more accurate representation of 90%, you can use the **Document Info panel** (Window > Document Info) to see the length of the path (circumference) which will vary based on size of the circle size... figure 90% of that measurement and that will provide you both the full dash to create a complete circle, and a percentage to use for the gap... round up to full points.

- i.e path is 780pt long, use 78pts for the dash = 10% gap.

This method gets "wonky" below 50% and is largely inaccurate for anything under 50% due to how dashes/gaps are applied to the stroke.

i.e. ... Based upon [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtpUn.png) there should be a small dash., but there isn't.

I generally only use this method for *visual* representation (above 50%) and not measured accuracy where values are concerned.

---

If **accuracy in % measurement is the goal**, using a pie chart and defining outer edges would work better in my opinion.

[image]

The Chart Data defines sizes, then merely ungroup the cart and adjust to strokes. While a 90/10 set p is relatively straightforward, this method makes things like a 82/18 or 76/24 setup much easier.

---

In addition, you are not limited to simply two pie "slices" you can enter multiple values and get multiple stroke sections equal to those values.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is cool, but how can you know if you hit 90%? Do you have to calculate the circle's circumference?

Comment: Answer updated with a "precision" method if that's what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, quicker, but not the most accurate option, is to copy that circle, duplicate and rotate:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> paste a duplicate circle in the same place
- <kbd>R</kbd> with this new circle selected, rotate until in comes to about 90%

Optionally, you can then merge these 2 circle objects into a single shape using the Pathfinder panel.