# How do you make an Android loading icon in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, android

I'd like to know how to make an android style loading icon in Illustrator. Can anyone help? It doesn't have to spin, i'd just like to know how to create the opacity on the circular object.

This is the one i'm talking about:

[image: Android loading icon]

Answer (score 10):

You can do this really easily in CS6 or later by applying a gradient to a stroke with a rounded end cap. I've circled the relevant appearance settings below:

[image: Illustrator Screenshot]

Older versions of Illustrator do not have the ability to apply gradients to strokes. If you don't have CS6+, you can an art brush instead. Follow the same technique described [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/31294/8708) (replace the straight bars with an expanded gradient).

Comment: Nice tutorial. I was able to make one in a few minutes. :)