# How to make a donut chart/segmented ring graph

Tags: adobe-photoshop, chart

I am looking for help in making a segmented ring effect in Photoshop.

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: There's no doubt I'd use Illustrator to create one of these, even if I had to bring it into Photoshop afterwards. Here's a question with a few methods for creating these in Illustrator: [**How do I make an incomplete circle stroke for a donut chart?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/31286/8708)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with JohnB. It would still be easy with Illustrator plus your icon is going to be scalable and it won't show pixels.

Anyway, **the Photoshop way**: (Please take note that there are a lot of ways of doing it. This is how I would do it)

First, make a circle:

[image]

Then, duplicate your first circle then change the second circle's color to **white**:

[image]

Then scale the new circle down just a little bit:

[image]

Grab your **Lasso Tool**;

[image]

Then draw a triangle-shaped selection according to your desired size of it:

[image]

Then make sure you are on your colored circle layer, then hit **delete** or **backspace** on your keyboard to delete the selected portion. Hit `**ctrl+D**` to **deselect** that portion you just selected

[image]

Add in your text and your done:

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is rasterized graph will not work for future use.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, I understand but he did ask for the Photoshop solution. I'd gladly do one for Illustrator if that's what he asks for.

Answer (score 0):

You can set exact graph as value

[See this Article](https://www.graphicadi.com/create-an-adjustable-donut-chart-in-photoshop/)

Hope this help.

Comment: I have added one link, please go through that

Answer (score 0):

This method keeps everything as vectors in Photoshop CC 2017

1. Create a circle using the Ellipse Tool. Set the stroke to blue and no fill.
2. Create a grey triangular segment using the Pen Tool (shape option). Set the fill to grey, stroke to none.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click in the layer panel on the line that separates both layers, this will create a vector clipping mask.
4. Type the text.

Example

[image: Example]