# How to specify the start & end position of a Linear Gradient?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, anchor-point, snapping

In Adobe Illustrator CC 2015 I can move a linear gradient as required with help of Gradient Annotator. But I don't see how to specify **exact** positions. Even more, Gradient Annotator doesn't snaps to anchor points and paths. What can you recommend?

Answer (score 6):

The *best* you can do is utilize the **Gradient Panel** and location **percentages**. Illustrator does not offer any hard algorithmic method to input definitive values. Because gradients are sized based on their boundaries, everything is relative to the object and a percentage. So if you want precision you'll need to do the math and figure out what percentage of the object matches your desired stop position. i.e. 100px object.. stop at 15px means 15%...

Using the **Gradient Panel** you can click a color stop and then alter the `Location` percentage to move the stop:

[image]

Note that clicking a color stop on the **annotator** will popup the options allowing you to adjust a color stop location as well:

[image]

---

You *can* be a bit more precise with linear gradient **angles** using the gradient *panel* as opposed to the annotator and use definitive degrees there:

[image]

This is about as precise as you'll get out of the box.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if you understand me correctly. When I say _start & end position_ I mean 2D points on the plot where gradient line starts and ends, not the locations of colors on the gradient bar. As for **angle** – this is helpful note.

Comment: @kelin I understand perfectly. Gradients in Illustrator start and stop at the *boundaries of the object they are applied to*. You can not start or stop a gradient at some offset point inside the object boundaries (i.e. there's no inner margin). Therefore the "start" point is the object's edge... and the "end" point is the object's edge opposite the start point.

Comment: If you are referring to gradients applied to strokes... you have even *less* control over things. There's no way to alter the start/end positions other than replicating color stops to make it *appear* as though colors begin at certain points. Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/22336/3270 or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/31298/3270 or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16944/3270

Comment: "Gradients in Illustrator start and stop at the boundaries of the object they are applied to." - you are definitely wrong. You can move around that points with help of the Annotator.

Comment: Sorry @kelin that is incorrect... you can move the first or last **color stop** (which I've explained in my answer) but you can not move the start and end point of the gradient.

Comment: If you move the annotator off the boundary of a shape.. doesn't the color follow the annotator? I mean, there's no "transparent gap" or "colorless area" between the object edge and the annotator end. Moving the annotator it's essentially like applying Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform > Move on the fill of the object. It moves the gradient fill, but it does not alter start and end points. The total gradient is *still* the same size as the object. The object itself becomes a pseudo clipping mask for the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to attempt to use the gradient mesh tool (shortcut U) to achieve a more precise gradient effect in your work. Note that mesh objects are not as easily manipulated as shapes in illustrator, so first  achieve the shape you want and then apply the mesh. You can precisely manipulate colors and positions on the mesh point by point in excruciating detail, unlike a simple gradient with the direct selection tool (A) around the mesh as you generate points with U.

The biggest issue you’ll have with mesh objects is easily editing them as they can be fickle things, so just be aware they are not well suited for simple designs, where layering standard objects is a better method. My other suggestion is to use as few mesh points as possible in your design — the more precise you are, the more precise you’ll have to be to achieve a clean look.

Comment: I've never worked with mesh before. Seems promising, but I need learn too much.

Comment: It's not a terribly difficult thing to mess with a bit. I'd check out YouTube for a start with it. It takes a while to master (I would not claim to have mastered it myself despite having been at this for several years), but with just one gradient mesh point you might achieve exactly what you're looking to achieve without touching a standard gradient.