# How do I add multiple sharp cornered strokes to a single Smart object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, stroke, smartobject

I'm working on a custom logo for a personal project that requires that certain smart object to have multiple strokes with sharp corners. For some unknown reason layers styles doesn't not provide an option to make the corners sharp and changing the smart object into a custom shape wont allow me to have multiple strokes.

So I'm stumped on how to procced further on my project if I cant solve this problem. Does anyone have a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More easily and quickly accomplished in Illustrator --

[How to add multiple strokes aligned 'outside' to a type layer in Illustrator CS6?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/how-to-add-multiple-strokes-aligned-outside-to-a-type-layer-in-illustrator-cs6)

Photoshop's Layer Style stroke **always** has rounded joints, *unless* the stroke is aligned to the *inside* of the layer. There's no way to change the round joints otherwise. So if rounded joints are a problem, you can't use layer styles unless the stroke is aligned to the inside of the layer. But, if aligned to the inside, strokes will cover the original image. And as strokes increase in size less and less of the actual image will be visible.

Photoshop's vector layers don't have an option for more than a single stroke. However, it would be possible to *duplicate* vector layers, stack them, and apply a *different* weight stroke to each duplicate layer, increasing in size, to accomplish something similar in Photoshop. i.e. vector layer 1 has an orange stroke of 3pt, vector layer 2 has a white stroke of 5pt, vector layer 3 has a red stroke of 10pt - as shown below.

[image]